# 'un-merge' multiple nested column headers in a matrix chart

Tags: reporting-services

I have spent far too long on this and would really appreciate any help someone is able to give.   I am creating a cross tab type report in SSRS (2012) using a matrix.  Everything is working fine - however my end result must have each column separated from the next (i.e. no merging on common groups).  I have three nested groups for the column groups (see figure) and want the output to show individual columns as opposed to merged on common groups.

I have seemingly exhausted all options - and am absolutely stuck - is anyone able to help?

[image: Output _Example]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your report design?

Comment: Thanks for for responding.  Is this suitable as a report design.   Your comment from last night - would this still be suitable?  Really appreciate your help.  Myles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive - I found by adding grouping appropriate to my report and then deleting the row and inserting rows inside the group and re entering the values worked.  These appear as 'static' in the advanced mode setting.